# Approve or decline Twitter follower requests without protected tweets

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to approve or decline Twitter follower requests if I don't check "protect my tweets" checkbox in my Twitter's setting?

I currently have 233 follower requests, I just approved 2 people that I'm sure I know of. I need to open my tweets publicly, but it's just really really annoying if I directly get more than 10 followers every day that I don't prefer them to follow me, and then I must block them one by one.

Comment: Following is a one-way street. They are just getting your new posts on a dashboard, nothing changes for you. Why do you want to have your tweets public but don't want anyone follow you? When people follow you this means either your tweets are interesting or they are some kinds of spam bots.

Comment: @neo, It doesn't mean I don't want anyone to follow me, I just want to know better my followers are really human people I interact well with, not machines. I saw more than 5 of my followers "asked me to follow them back" whom I don't know them all. I'm suspicious they're spam bots, I'm just worried if I let them (people/machines I don't know) follow me they'll reveal my twitter account password soon. cmiiw or should I just ignore them and open my tweets publicly? :-/ _confused_ Thanks for responding so quickly.

Comment: @Arie Keren: Your followers don't have more access to data than anyone else. You can safely ignore their requests. If they do seem spammy you may block them, but it doesn't matter really.

Comment: You can use a tool like [Topify](http://www.topify.com) which gives you more informative new follower notification, so you can better understand who new followers are and decide whether to block them or not. Plus it has other neat features like follow back by simply replying to the email notification.

Comment: @neo, OK, I reopened my tweets publicly, accepted all of those requests, and I'll monitor what would happen.

Comment: @Dmitry, Privet, maybe this kind of tool I need, I'll give it a try, thanks for the sharing!

Comment: @Arie, +1 for privet :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing an important point of what is the purpose of Twitter.
It's a micro-blog, the act of "tweeting" is by default by public.

So you can block users, but it cannot change the fact that they will still be able to see your tweets, while not logged in.

`twitter.com/<username>`

is viewable by all and does not reach a privacy barrier in the same way as for example Facebook

`facebook.com/<username>`

So the answer is no, the only proper way would be to protect your tweets.

Answer (score 3):

You can always block unwanted followers.

To block a Twitter user:

1. **Log in** to your Twitter account.
2. **Go to the profile page** of the person you wish to block.
3. **Click the person icon**. This brings up a drop-down Actions menu.
4. Select **Block** from the options listed.

From here: http://support.twitter.com/articles/117063-how-to-block-users-on-twitter

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. Please see my comment at my question above.

Comment: @Arie, it's the best possible answer for what you want to do.  When you don't have protected tweets then the term "follower request" doesn't make any sense.  When you don't protect your tweets, blocking or not blocking is the only option.  I read the comment thread and Topify would only support you in this task.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, see this Q from Twitter's [FAQs About Following](https://support.twitter.com/articles/14019-faqs-about-following):

> **How do I approve followers?**
>
> If you have [protected your Tweets](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169886-how-to-protect-and-unprotect-your-tweets), you can approve followers from your account home page. [Click here](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169376-how-to-approve-deny-follower-requests) to learn how.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this extension for Chrome in order to accept/approve all follower requests.

[Twitter Accept ALL button](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/twitter-accept-all-button/aoldpodihmiiijjcgkcddgcdhaloejdf)

> Approve all follower requests in ONE-click. Extension adds special button to Twitter.

Comment: How does this answer the question?